# sort a dynamic set of data using Google Apps Script

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script

I have a block of data like this in a new spreadsheet:

```
GOODS       Count    Sort Index
111770999     128    9
111771000     32     0
111771005     64     5
111771010     64     0
111771011     64     1
```

number of rows are dynamic, columns are fixed (3).  How can i write a script to sort by column 3 like using `Data-Sort` Range in the spreadsheet?  Many thanks in advance!

Comment: currently i'm doing it manually; but i'd like to try it using Google Apps Script

Answer (score 0):

You can sort like this using appscript:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('YOUR_SHEET_NAME');
sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,sheet.getLastColumn()).sort(3);

//Here, getRange is(startingRow,startingColumn,NumRows,NumCols) 
//and sort(x) represents sort by 'x'th column
```